# Do these predicate logic translations make sense?

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

Please help with the predicate logic translations for these!

(1)Every friend didn't vote.

∀x(F(x)→ ¬V(x))

(2)Alex is reckless and he lives in Portland, if he is a friend

this has two interpretations:

--> Alexi is reckless and if he is a friend then he lives in Portland.

∀a(R(a) ∧(F(a) → L(a,p)))

--> If Alexi is a friend, then he is reckless and he lives in Portland

∀a(F(a) → (R(a) ∧ L(a,p)))

Comment: Indeed. The problem is ill posed and is an English language problem rather than a math problem. (I assume that, once you've settled down on one of the meanings of (2), you can do the rest.) I *guess* that, because there is no comma after "reckless" but there is one before "if", the second interpretation is more likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alexi is a specific individual, so you should not use a quantifier for that, but rather an individual constant. Put differently: just like you treat the $p$ as an individual constant to denote Portland, you should treat the $a$  you are using as an individual constant for Alexi, and do not quantify either of them; only variables get quantified!

So, for 2 you get either

$$R(a) \land (F(a) \rightarrow L(a,p))$$

Or

$$F(a) \rightarrow (R(a) \land L(a,p))$$